# Set into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, normalization

I have the following data

```
SQL> SELECT id, relatedIdInASet from tab;

+----+------------------+
| id | relatedIdInASet  |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | [12,34,56]       |
| 2  | [11,12,22,34]    |
+----+------------------+
```

`relatedIdInASet` is `text` type up to 1024 chars, each row can contain different amount of IDs. we are able to use `find_in_set` function on it, but we can't index it... I want to normalize the data. I would like to create a table using a SQL to decouple the set so it will result:

```
+----+------------+
| id | relatedId  |
|---+-------------+
| 1  | 12         |
| 1  | 34         |
| 1  | 56         |
| 2  | 11         |
| 2  | 12         |
| 2  | 22         |
| 2  | 34         |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a split string function.

In your case I suggest following the below steps.

1.Update tab table removing the `[` and `]` , this can be done in a simple update :

```
update tab
set relatedIdInASet = replace(replace(relatedIdInASet, '[', ''),']','');
```

2.Create a numbers table with the maximum length of the largest row on your table, in your example it is 4.

```
create  table numbers (
  n int );

insert into numbers values (1),(2),(3),(4);
```

3.Split the string:

```
select id, 
       substring_index( substring_index(relatedIdInASet, ',', n),',', -1) as relatedIdInASet
from tab
join numbers
  on char_length(relatedIdInASet) 
    - char_length(replace(relatedIdInASet, ',', '')) 
    >= n - 1;
```

You could create tab2 table directly:

```
create table tab2 as select 
  id, 
  substring_index( substring_index(relatedIdInASet, ',', n),',', -1) as relatedIdInASet
from tab
join numbers
  on char_length(relatedIdInASet) 
    - char_length(replace(relatedIdInASet, ',', '')) 
    >= n - 1 ;
```

*All the mentioned steps can be found on [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/6qqwbWXf)*